# How can i get the value using functions in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to use React Hook for fetching data from API and display it in browser,Since i tried to use filter on the state array i am unable to get the output.

I have defined state as follows:

```
   const [selectedPerson, setselectedPerson] = useState(null);
   const [totalData, setTotalData] = useState([]);
   const [isfinalData, setIsfinalData] = useState(false);
   const [Bagmati, setBagmati] = useState([]);
   const [Bagmatitotal, setBagmatitotal] = useState([]);
   const [Bagdist, setBagdist] = useState([]);
```

following below are my codes:

```
             <select className="form-control" onChange={(e) => {

                        console.log(e.target.value);
                        let FinalDistrict = Bagmati.filter((item) => item.district === 
                        e.target.value)
                        console.log(FinalDistrict);
                         }} >
                        <option >Choose District</option>
                        {Bagdist.map((item, _id) => <option key={_id} value={item.id}> 
                        {item.title_ne}</option>)}


                        </select>
```

Following Below is my Output:I provided value 28 and got empty array as output shown below in Bagmati Data.

[image]

But in same code if i provide value 28 manually than i can get output,as shown below:
Following is the code i have given manual value:

```
                        <select className="form-control" onChange={(e) => {

                        console.log("my value is >>", 28);
                        let FinalDistrict = Bagmati.filter((item) => item.district === 28)
                        setBagmati(FinalDistrict);
                        }} >
                        <option >Choose District</option>
                        {Bagdist.map((item, _id) => <option key={_id} value={item.id}> 
                        {item.title_ne}</option>)}


                         </select>
```

And my output is :

[image]

why is this happening?What may be the solution?

Comment: did you try `parseInt(e.target.value)` instead of just `e.target.value`? Your `e.target.value` is 
a string while the `item.district` is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value from `input` is type `string`, and when you check it with Strict Equality Comparison `===`,
it will return false.
You can use `Number(e.target.value)` to convert it to `Number`:

```
Bagmati.filter(item => item.district === Number(e.target.value))
```